# Looking for a singular word or term to denote a question that is non accusatory

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Can anyone suggest a singular word or term, if one even exits, for a question that is non accusatory in nature. I know it’s a strange question so I’ll give very simple examples

Mom
WHY DID YOU DO IT? 
If say for example the son broke a vase. This is a question but an accusation as well. It attributes blame.

As opposed to say

Mom 
Why did you do it? 
If she was asking her son why he worked out his maths question the way he did as opposed to a different way.

Or

Police officer

Sir, where were you on the night of so and so. This appears to be a neutral question or an inquiry that doesn’t attribute an accusatory nature!

Is there a term or a singular word that denotes the difference. Would it be an insinuationary question or just an insinuation or inference?? or an interrogation or a neutral question.

A question that doesn’t denote blame or accusation. An inquiry perhaps

Comment: The question does not entail blame. The tone of voice does.

Comment: correction: insinuating question.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: What about those based on the complex-question fallacy? "When did you stop beating your wife?" No matter how mildly you put that, it is a question that assigns blame.

Comment: @Robusto:  Righto. The question in OP's example I should have said. But I will fall back on **the** :)

Answer (score 2):

**In the law, they call those loaded questions:**

**Why** did you murder your husband? [Why did you break the vase?]
versus
**Did** you murder your husband? [Did you break the vase?]

The first question assumes there was a murder, the second does not and just asks if the person committed the act.

[loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)

Comment: I think they call them "leading" questions.

Comment: No, those are different.  You can go and see for yourself on Wikipedia like I did. The traditional example is the question "Have you stopped beating your wife?" Whether the respondent answers yes or no, he will admit to having a wife and having beaten her at some time in the past.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  as Lambie says (and I didn't know) these are indeed different.  In the courtroom, at least, *loaded* questions are usually *leading questions*, but not vice-versa.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't know either until I looked it  up. :)

Comment: By **in the law**, I thought Lambie was referring to the term of art.  No lawyer would say "Objection, Your Honor. That's a loaded question."  The lawyer would say, "Objection, Your Honor. The question assumes facts not in evidence."

Comment: The type of question is known as a loaded question. When lawyers ask loaded questions, the other side often objects, and the judge will often sustain the objection. It's a minor thing. I could have written in law or in the law and still have elicited the remark. And, not every term of art is what a lawyer says.

Answer (score 0):

We speak of **innocent questions** and **simple questions**, to distinguish them from questions which "have an agenda" other than wanting to know something.

Comment: The main point is that a loaded question assumes an thing was done: Why did you  kill your wife? (Why did you break the vase?)  As opposed to: Did you kill your wife? (Did you break the vase?). The legal example is just a very famous example.